# Why is my hidden HTML form field showing up?

Tags: html, forms, hidden-field

I'm trying to put some data in a hidden form field for a POST. But the field is showing up on my Web page. There are no styles or style sheet.  Here's how the fields are defined.  Any ideas?

```
    <form action="GetUserPics.php" method="post">
        <input type=”hidden” name=”picIndex” value="WHAT?">
        <input type="submit" value="previous">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using non-standard quotation marks for your attributes on that field. HTML is interpreting those quotes as part of the attribute's value, as in:

```
<input type="”hidden”" name="”picIndex”" value="WHAT?">
```

Since `”hidden”` is not a valid input type, it's reverting to `text`.

Comment: Bizarre.  I have no idea where those quotation marks came from.  This was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not using ASCII quotes, you're using some sort of weird slanty quotes that the HTML is trying to use as the type (and thus it will fall back to text).  Interestingly, you're not using them to print the `value`, which incidentally hides your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=”hidden” name=”picIndex” value="WHAT?">
```

Those are not regular double quotes. Try

```
    <input type="hidden" name="picIndex" value="WHAT?">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your hidden type input with this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="picIndex" value="WHAT?"/>
```